# Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number with pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet

I am working with python and pyspark in a jupyter notebook. I am trying to read several parquet files from an aws s3 bucket and convert them into a single json file.

This is what I have:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


bucket = s3.Bucket(name='mybucket')

keys =[]
for key in bucket.objects.all():
    keys.append(key.key)
    
print(keys[0])

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# initialise sparkContext
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local') \
    .appName('myAppName') \
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '5gb') \
    .config("spark.cores.max", "6") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
```

But I am getting:

```
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number with pyspark
```

I am not sure how to fix this, thank you!

Comment: One possible reason maybe that the JAVA_HOME is not set because java is not installed.

Comment: Is there a way to install java in a python3 jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Your getting this error because your pyspark is not able to communicate with your cluster. you need to set the value of some global variable like this.

```
import os
import findspark
findspark.init()

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = """--name job_name --master yarn / local
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
pyspark-shell""" 

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = "python3.6" # what ever version of python your using
os.environ['python'] = "python3.6"
```

findspark package is optional but it's good to use in case of pyspark.

Comment: Thank you! What goes in the '--name' and 'job_name' argument?

Comment: the name of your job this name you can see on the spark UI or on the Yarn UI where you can see all the running job in the cluster

Comment: findspark should be the first line of code before importing any packages like pyspark or SparkSession from pyspark